# AWS assume role using an AWS EKS IRSA role

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, identity-management

I am trying to assume a role from an eks container that has an IRSA role attached to it. however when I assume a role, I can see that the container is using the ec2 iam role instead or the IRSA role.

```
[I] ✦2 ➜ kubectl get sa web -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/web
```

assume role from inside the container

```
CREDENTIALS=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "$ROLE_ARN" --role-session-name "$ROLE_SESSION_NAME")
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/eks-instance/role/i-02xxxxxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::yyyyyyyyyy:role/app
Cleaning up file based variables
```

aws sts get-caller-identity returns the ec2 iam role.

Comment: whats the response of `aws sts get-caller-identity`

Comment: This returns the role that is attached to the ec2 instance.

Comment: Do you see the OpenID Connect-related environment variables inside the pod?  Are you running a new enough version of the AWS SDK/CLI?  Have you done the setup to allow the EKS OpenID identities to assume the IAM role?